# jquery triggerHandler doesn't work while trigger does

Tags: event-handling, jquery, jquery-triggerhandler, jquery-trigger

I am adding a click event to a checkbox which will show/hide additional fields depending on its checked status. I want the handler to fire on load to set up the initial page structure.   For some reason triggerHandler is not working on the field. If I change it to 'trigger' the handler will fire, but the checkbox status will also change.  Can you see what i've done wrong/why triggerHandler won't work?

```
$('body').on("click", "#hdimage", function(){
    console.log('hd');
    if(!$('#hdimage').is(':checked')){
        $('.sd-dim').hide();
    } else {
        $('.sd-dim').show();
    }
});
$('#hdimage').triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens [(*as described in the docs*)](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) because

> Events created with `.triggerHandler()` **do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy**; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.

and since you use the delegated syntax of the `.on()` method which lets `body` handle the `click` event that occurs on the `#hdimage` element, that event never reaches the `body`..

Answer (score 0):

Your Event is not bound to "#hdimage" its bound to 'body'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hdimage').on("click", function(){
        alert("dostuff")
    });
    $('#hdimage').triggerHandler('click');
});
```